# The URL for internal web applictaion(php) some times shows not available

Tags: php, url

the URL for our internal application(PHP) some times shows not available. it is working fine with IP address. 
Some times only working with URL.

can any one give me the solution

thanks
Naren

Comment: We're not in a philosophy course, please provide more informations.

Comment: From all the information you have provided it sounds like you need a new DNS server

Answer (score 0):

Please check your internet connection (if you are testing this on live server). If you are testing this locally, provide more information about your environment.

Are you getting htaccess error or something else?